# Should I have "installation" feature / scenario?

Tags: testing, installation, automated-tests, bdd

I'm creating BDD tests for a shop-system plugin. Before plugin features can be tested, plugin has to be installed in shop's admin page and configured on additional page.

1. Should I create "installation" feature / scenario? If yes, should I make every other test dependent of it?
2. Should I make the installation and configuration a part of "Given that plugin is installed"?
3. Should I assume that plugin will be installed and configured properly and I should not test it?
4. Should I create "reinstallation" feature, instead of "installation" to make feature independent?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use Background (assuming you use Cucumber) allows to add context to the scenario. I think it will answer on all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the tests in your suite require the installation then add it into your before hook.  If not all of them do then use a background step in your feature files.